# How do I check the type of a function parameter?

Tags: types, rust

I have a function:

```
fn my_function(my_float:f32) -> f32{
     my_float - 1.55
}
```

With this function, if I pass an integer, (of course) I get an error:

```
expected type f32 found type {integer}
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to handle the error from inside the function (or any other way), e.g. if a user passes a string or an integer or another type.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you _want_ the compiler to let the user of that function pass something else other than an `f32`? Moving these type checks from compile-time to run-time is unusual and not beneficial.

Comment: How would you expect to handle it? The error is from the code calling it, not the user of that code, so generally the user would rather not have the wrong sort of value to be passable at all.

Comment: The concept of having the error comming from inside Vs outside the function doesn't really make much sense as it's still an error, an the rust type system doesn't give you much in the way of options to do something different. Possibly your looking for generic functions?

Comment: @E_net4: exactly, because the value should be f32 but if it is not f32 I need to record (log) the error into a file

Comment: @user1937198: I'll look into generic functions (thanks). Maybe I should not force f32 at all and check (if possible) the type inside the function

Comment: As the answer below suggests, if the function parameter is `f32`, then you can never pass something else. So it can never happen, and there is nothing to record.

Comment: @E_net4: imagine something running on a server: a user (client) can pass something wrong. You can say: you should carefully check what the user can submit and that's ok. But imagine a case where there's no check of client code.

Comment: In that case you would also need a function taking some other type representing the user's input, not just a function taking an `f32`. Otherwise you would not be able to represent it in Rust code. This isn't very different from other statically typed languages, such as C++.

Comment: @E_net4thedownvoteapologist: ok, now I understand it better, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust is a statically typed, compiled language. As such, it fixes the types of each function at compile time. That is, usually you decide what types your function accepts.

If you just want to pass different things to your function, you could employ generics:

```
fn doit<T>(t: T) {...}
```

This way, you can pass different things to `doit`, but you still have to decide at compile time.

Now, there are possibilities to pass different things into a function at runtime.

One possibility would be to create an enum:

```
enum MyType {
    F32(f32),
    Str(String),
    USize(usize),
}
```

Then, your function could accept a parameter of `MyType`, and could decide what to do. This approach requires you to specify upfront (i.e. at compile time) which types you want to allow for your function.

Another run-time approach could involve `Any`:

```
fn doit(t: &dyn std::any::Any) {
    match t.downcast_ref::<usize>() {
        Some(u) => println!("its usize: {}", u),
        None => println!("not usize"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    doit(&2usize);
    doit(&("sdf".to_string()));
}
```

I generally prefer to do as much as possible at compile-time since it tends to catch bugs earlier.